# VS debugger causing WCF IDispatchMessageInspector to stop getting hit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, debugging

This is related to another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122630/attaching-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013-gives-different-behaviour), but thought I would ask it in a different light because it might be for a different audience than the original name implies.

I have a fairly complex solution running in .NET 4.5.1 and Silverlight 5, various WCF and ASMX web services, and when I run with "Start debugging" all is fine. However, If I start it without debugging, I seem to lose a custom IDispatchMessageInspector that I am applying via a custom endpoint to a WCF service.

This message inspector pulls out a custom http header value that I insert in the message sent to the service, and eventually this value ends up in the DB. I have some logs in place to confirm this message inspector is getting hit.

When I am debugging via VS2013 all is fine, and I see the header get pulled out and the value written to the DB, and the logs I am dumping back this fact up. However, if I detach the debugger, the logs don't come out anymore from that message inspector (though I see all of my other logs in the service), and the header value is no longer pulled out and inserted into the DB. I do know the service is getting hit though, because the rest of the data that comes out of the service itself is still written to the DB correctly, and I see the appropriate logs.

If I attach back to the same w3wp.exe instance, those values start appearing again.

I would have had a hard time believing it had to do with debugging, but it is the only difference in the two scenarios.

I'm really stuck on this one, so any guidance would be appreciated!

My configuration is as follows for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="customBehaviour" type="Services.Common.CustomBehaviourExtensionElement, Services.Common"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehaviour">
          <customBehaviour/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity" contract="Services.Interfaces.Net.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NoSecurity" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was actually a problem with the IClientMessageInspector on the sending side. For some reason after attaching the debugger, the request.Properties collection did not contain a HttpRequestMessageProperty ("httpRequest"), so my custom header had nowhere to be placed and failed out. The IDispathMessageInspector was getting hit on the receiving end, it just didn't have anything to read out of the header.

My solution was to add this property in the IClientMessageInspector if it wasn't found, then add my header info.

I still don't understand why detaching the debugger produces this behaviour (with the debugger attached the property was always there), but I have at least been able to work around it.